# Forecast experimental results based on temperature

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would really welcome any hints on making this code more concise please.
In this example we have some experiment results.
For each planned experiment We have predicted results based on 4 temperatures and we have 4 forecasted results, 1 for each of the temperature.

For each experiment when the actual experiment is received, we need
to find it's predicted results and use the actual result to find between which 2
temperatures did the result fall between and then use the prediction values corresponding to those temperatures.

i.e. if the actual result is between the values for `Temp_10` and `Temp_15` we know we have to use
`Predicted_Result_10` and `Predicted_Result_15`.

I would welcome any suggestions on how to make this more concise and most labs will have at least 18 temperatures and 18 predicted results and also cater for different labs that have more that 18. I will know for each lab how many they will have ie
USA Lab has 25 temperatures and 25 predicted results
UK Lab has 20  temperatures and 20 predicted results
AUS Lab has 18 temperatures and 18 predicted results

Thanks for your time

```
import pandas as pd

predicted_data = [['A',35,36,37,37,11.1955,11.8546,12.3809,12.8378],
                 ['B',38,36,38,37,9.2410,9.7486,10.1248,10.4282],
                  ['C',34,35,35,39,9.2686,9.7707,10.1330,10.4166]
                ]

result_data = [['A',11.3],
               ['B',10.11],
               ['C',9.53]]

predicted_df = pd.DataFrame(predicted_data,columns=['Experiment','Predicted_Result_10','Predicted_Result_15', \
                                                    'Predicted_Result_20','Predicted_Result_30', \
                                'Temp_10','Temp_15','Temp_20','Temp_30'])
print (predicted_df)
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data,columns=['Experiment','Result'])
print (result_df)

def dummy_function (predicted_result1: float, predicted_result2: float):
    # actual function is more complex
    print ('calculation using ', predicted_result1, predicted_result2)
    return predicted_result1 + predicted_result2

Experiment_A_result = 0
Experiment_B_result = 0
Experiment_C_result = 0

for index,result in result_df.iterrows():
   # search predicted results for each experiment
    # print (predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']])
    # print ( ' actual result ',result['Result'])
   # print (type(result['Result']))
    # print (predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_10'])

    # For an actual result, we want to find which 2 Temp columns from the predicted data does the actual
    # result fall between. Having found those 2 columns
    if (predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_10'].iloc[0]) <= result['Result'] \
        < predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_15'].iloc[0]:
        print (' do a calculation  using the predicted results 10 and 15 as they match the range')
        my_result = dummy_function(predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_10'].iloc[0],
                                   predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_15'].iloc[0])
    elif (predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_15'].iloc[0]) <= result['Result'] \
        < predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_20'].iloc[0]:
        print (' do a calculation  using the predicted results 15 and 20 as they match the range')
        my_result = dummy_function(
            predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_15'].iloc[0],
            predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_20'].iloc[0])
    elif (predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_20'].iloc[0]) <= result['Result'] \
        < predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Temp_30'].iloc[0]:
        print (' do a calculation  using the predicted results 20 and 30 as they match the range')
        my_result = dummy_function(predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_20'].iloc[0],
                                   predicted_df.loc[predicted_df['Experiment'] == result['Experiment']]['Predicted_Result_30'].iloc[0])
    if result['Experiment'] == 'A':
        Experiment_A_result = Experiment_A_result + my_result
    elif result['Experiment'] == 'B':
        Experiment_B_result = Experiment_B_result + my_result
    else: Experiment_C_result = Experiment_C_result + my_result
```

Comment: hi @Reinderien I just cut and paste this code into pycharm and it executed

Comment: My mistake; I missed a keyword. Anyway, placeholder, stub or hypothetically abridged code is not considered on topic for Code Review. Please post the whole function.

Comment: Once you have provided your actual code, we can re-open the question.

Comment: @Newbie Your edit is not enough - the code is still hypothetical. Please show your real code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data are misshapen. Rather than having a separate `Temp_` column per... what are those (10, 15, etc.)? Temperatures? There should be an index level per experiment and temperature, and your `Result` column should have 3 * 4 = 12 rows, due to the cartesian product of those index levels.

Don't write `_data` lists, and don't separately define your `columns`. Just pass a dict into the `DataFrame` constructor directly whose keys correspond to the columns.

Your `dummy_function` needs to be deleted and replaced with an aggregate `.sum()`.

Don't `iterrows` except as a last resort. More importantly, and I'm sure this is you refusing to show what your real code is doing, your `my_result` is mostly meaningless because it overwrites itself on every iteration. I am going to assume that you really only care about the last row, which is what this loop would deliver; and so delete the loop altogether.

Your chained `if` statements don't have good behaviour at the edges: what if the experimental result is outside of the range of the predicted results? Currently, you don't initialise `my_result` at all. All of those `if`s should be replaced by a call to `searchsorted`.

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd

predicted_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
          'Temp': (11.1955, 11.8546, 12.3809, 12.8378,  9.2410,  9.7486, 10.1248, 10.4282,  9.2686,  9.7707, 10.1330, 10.4166),
        'Result': (35,      36,      37,      37,      38,      36,      38,      37,      34,      35,      35,      39),
    }, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        names=('Experiment', 'Base_Temp'),
        iterables=(
            ('A', 'B', 'C'),
            (10, 15, 20, 30),
        ),
    ),
)

result_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Result': (11.30, 10.11, 9.53)},
    index=predicted_df.index.unique('Experiment'),
)

print(predicted_df)
print(result_df)

result = result_df.iloc[-1:]
experiment = predicted_df.loc[result.index]
y, = experiment.Temp.searchsorted(result.Result)
if 0 < y < experiment.shape[0]:
    my_result = experiment.Result.iloc[y-1: y+1].sum()
    print(my_result)
```

### Output

```
                         Temp  Result
Experiment Base_Temp                 
A          10         11.1955      35
           15         11.8546      36
           20         12.3809      37
           30         12.8378      37
B          10          9.2410      38
           15          9.7486      36
           20         10.1248      38
           30         10.4282      37
C          10          9.2686      34
           15          9.7707      35
           20         10.1330      35
           30         10.4166      39
            Result
Experiment        
A            11.30
B            10.11
C             9.53
69
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your review I appreciate it.  The actual function hasn't been written yet so I could not supply it, this looks really good I will step through it in debugger.  Thanks again this is a big help

Comment: hi Reinderin, thanks again for this, jst wondering it looks to me that mysult is only calculated for Experiment C, you mentioned not to use iterrows except as last resort, what should I do to get my_result calculated for each expereiment please?

Comment: @Newbie I'll show you, but you need to edit your question to do it. Your question's code needs to be more realistic, as it currently overwrites all results with those of experiment C.

Comment: thanks I have edited to store result per experiment